# How do I run by attached a function

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

now i have create a code to calculate a formula but i have a problem with number 4,5,6,7 it can select but it not running. working principle of code is select a number in the box click enter and it will enter into that formula.i think my problem is a case function but i tried to fix and it can't.
....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<windows.h>
#define PI 3.14159
using namespace std;

HANDLE h=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//set Color
void colorText(int i){
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,i);
}
//Declaring Variable
float density(float mass, float volume){
return mass / (double)volume;
}
int exponent(int base,int index,int result){
return result = pow(base, index);
}
float hypotenuse(float A_side, float B_side,float c_side_result){
return c_side_result = sqrt((A_side*A_side)+(B_side*B_side)); 
}
float velocity(float velo, float initial, float acceleration, float time){
return velo = initial + (acceleration * time);
}
float mass_en(float mass_value, float speedlight_value, float energy){
return energy = mass_value * (speedlight_value * speedlight_value);
}
float percentage(float percent, float number, float base_per){
return percent = (number/base_per)*100;
}   
// Main Menu
void main_Menu(){
colorText(11);
system("CLS");
cout << "----------------------\n";
cout << "*  6 Useful formula  *\n";
cout << "----------------------\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"1.finding density \n";
cout << setw(3)<<"2.finding exponent\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"3.finding hypotenuse\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"4.finding velocity\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"5.finding mass\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"6.finding percentage\n";
cout << setw(3)<<"7.member\n";
cout << "----------------------\n";
}

//single Menu
void density_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "*  finding Density  *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}
void exponent_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "* finding Exponent  *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}
void hypotenuse_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "* finding Hypotenuse  *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}
void velocity_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "* finding Velocity  *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}
void mass_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "*   finding Mass    *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}
void percentage_menu(){
system("CLS");
cout << "---------------------\n";
cout << "* finding percentage *\n";
cout << "---------------------\n";
}


int main(){
char choosechoice;
do{
main_Menu();
cout << "Press X or x to exit: ";
cin >> choosechoice;

switch(choosechoice){
case '1':
system("CLS");
float mass, volume;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
density_menu();
cout << "Enter Mass: ";
cin >> mass;
cout << "Enter Volume: ";
cin >> volume;
system("CLS");
density_menu();
cout << setw(10)<<"Mass: " << setw(6)<<mass << " kg"<< endl;
cout << setw(10)<<"Volume: " << setw(6)<<volume << " m^3"<< endl;
cout << setw(10)<<"Density: " << setw(6)<<density(mass,volume)<<" kg/m^3";
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '2':
system("CLS");
int base, index, result;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
exponent_menu();
cout << "Enter Base number: ";
cin >> base;
cout << "Enter Index number: ";
cin >> index;
system("CLS");
exponent_menu();
cout << setw(15)<<"Base number: " << setw(6)<<base << endl;
cout << setw(15)<<"Index number: " << setw(6)<<index << endl;
cout << setw(15)<<"Result: " << setw(6)<<exponent(base,index,result);
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '3':
system("CLS");
float A_side,B_side,c_side_result;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
hypotenuse_menu();
cout << "Enter A side: ";
cin >> A_side;
cout << "Enter B side: ";
cin >> B_side;
system("CLS");
hypotenuse_menu();
cout << setw(10)<<"Result: " << setw(6)<<hypotenuse(A_side,B_side,c_side_result);
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '4':
system("CLS");
float velo, initial, acceleration, time;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
velocity_menu();
cout << "Enter initial velocity: ";
cin >> initial;
cout << "Enter acceleration : ";
cin >> acceleration;
cout << "Enter time : ";
cin >> time;
system("CLS");
velocity_menu();
cout << setw(10)<<"Result: " << setw(6)<<velocity(velo,initial,acceleration,time);
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '5':
system("CLS");
float mass_value, speedlight_value, energy;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
mass_menu();
cout << "Enter Mass Value: ";
cin >> mass_value;
cout << "Enter Speed of light value : ";
cin >> speedlight_value;
system("CLS");
mass_menu();
cout << setw(10)<<"Result: " << setw(6)<<mass_en(mass_value, speedlight_value, energy);
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '6':
system("CLS");
float percent, number, base_per;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
mass_menu();
cout << "Type the number: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "Type the base: ";
cin >> base_per;
system("CLS");
percentage_menu();
cout << setw(10)<<"Result: " << setw(6)<<percentage(percent, number, base_per);
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;

case '7':
system("CLS");
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
cout << "---------------------------\n";
cout << "            MEMBER         \n";
cout << "Nattapon Sripradub M.4/1 No.14\n";
cout << "Natnicha  Nuangsupthawee M.4/1 No.22\n";
cout << "Panicha Pornpattarapon M.4/1 No.24\n";
cout << "\n----------------------";
cout << "\nPress any key to return to main menu";
getch();
break;
   
}
}while(choosechoice!= 'X' && choosechoice != 'x');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: _i have a problem with number 4,5,6,7_ What problem? Compiler error? Unexpected behavior at runtime? Please, [edit] your question and be more specific. -- At a second glance, I noticed that you didn't write input statements for all variables you want to use in the resp. functions afterwards. -- Furthermore, I expect issues concerning the `getch();`. If you input a number you have to confirm by [Enter] but the `std::cin >>` will leave this `\n` (caused by the [Enter]) in the input buffer. I wouldn't wonder if `getch()` doesn't seem to be effective...

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?